# Notation for difference of two random variables

Tags: notation, convolution

Is there any standard notation for the distribution of the difference of two random variables. For the sum of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, we can write,

$f_{X + Y}(t) = (f_X \ast f_Y)(t)$

but I can't seem to find any standard notation for representing the difference.

Edit: To clarify, $X$ and $Y$ are independent continous random variables. I could write out the whole equation,

$f_{X-Y}(t) = \int_{t'} f_X(t') f_Y(t'-t) dt'$

but I was wondering if there is some notation similar to that for convolution where I could just write

$f_{X-Y}(t) = f_X(t) \ast f_Y(-t)$

Note: The $\ast$ symbol is used in the Wikipedia page for convolution here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution.

Comment: The notation $f_{X-Y}(t) = f_X(t) \ast f_Y(-t)$ should be avoided since the convolution is an operation between functions, not between the two numbers $f_X(t)$ and $f_Y(-t)$. If one insists on having a notation for the function $$h(t)=\int f(y+t)g(y)dy=\int f(x)g(x-t)dx$$ one could define $$\tilde g(y)=g(-y)$$ and note that $$h=f\ast\tilde g$$ For example, $$f_{X-Y}=f_X\ast\tilde f_Y$$

Comment: @Did That looks nice. The reason I want to write it like this is because I don't introduce any symbols for the random variables themselves and only define the densities. In addition, the fact that it is an integral is unimportant (it will most likely be computed numerically anyways), so I want a simple way to represent that. Anyways, I think this looks nice so I will use it. Thanks!